# rpart not displaying a plot

Tags: r, plot, rpart

I am new to R and I am trying to build a decision tree using rpart.
However when I plotted the model using plot(fit) where fit = model, the output displayed was all lines and no texts/ no variable names. Is there anything that must be wrong with my settings?

Comment: See [example](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/rpart/html/plot.rpart.html) at ?plot.rpart

Comment: I did exactly as what was in the example but no text shows up in the plot

Comment: Did you add the line `text(fit, use.n = TRUE)` after `plot(fit)` ?

Comment: Yes. But the variables it displays are garbled (ex: State = abfhjkmoqtvxyz), which is not part of my data set.

Comment: Please provide a example data and your code that can replicate your error. Difficult to pinpoint your issue and provide any answer without more information.